# transfer pdfs in ibooks to PC

Tags: ipad

On my iPad, I graded student assignments by marking opening emails in a browser, opening pdf attachments in iBooks, and editing those pdfs with a stylus. Is there anyway to get these pdfs off the iPad without another Apple device? None of the suggested methods work:

1. On iTunes I see a "Books" folder, but it is empty, "No files".
2. iBooks says it is syncing all files to iCloud. Based on the count it gives for the # of files synced, the assignments are being sync'd. If I go to icloud.com, there are no books present, however. If I install the iBooks application on a windows machine, it syncs an "iCloud Drive" directory that doesn't include a single books.
3. When I open the pdf in iBooks and click on "share" the only option I see is "print" or "Airdrop".
4. Third party apps including iExplorer and EaseUS Mobimover don't see any books on the device or browsing the iTunes backup. The apps acknowledge Apple is always making changes to thwart access, so this should be expected.
5. I installed dropbox on the iPad, but it doesn't see the iBooks material.

There are is no DRM here. These are my pdfs. This is a 2020 iPad Pro running iOS 14.4.2. Did Apple remove all ways to use the pdf I created without buying another Apple device to Airdrop with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here’s how I do the same .

First open the iBooks app , toggle at the 3 small dots , press share , then press save to files , there you can save it the existing folders like GarageBand etc or you can create your own folder . Note - save the file in the iPad and not in the iCloud Drive . I suggest you save it in the GarageBand folder - makes the whole process easier . Then - open iTunes connect your iPad , open the GarageBand folder , you can see the required files there . Even the third party apps like Ease US Mobimover and Dropbox can detect the files . Let me know if you still have any doubts .

Note : the GarageBand folder is found in the file sharing section in iTunes .

Hope this helps

Comment: The iBooks app is braindead. I have 200 PDFs, but iBooks only lets you transfer one file at a time. It's 2022 and there's still no way to sync multiple PDFs to a computer at once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a page that claims to answer: https://www.alphr.com/read-ibooks-windows/
But I haven’t tried it.  Probably out of date.

If you have an iBooks app from Apple on Windows, and the PDF is in it, try dragging its icon to desktop or a folder.  That works in MacBook.

If that doesn’t work, with the PDF open in Books on the iPad, click the share icon:[image]
Select Mail to send a copy of it to yourself.